# jQuery pagination with dynamic <li>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pagination

I use this plugin to paginate my `<li>` : http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-quick-pagination-list-items/

The list derived from `select` option with `onchange` method. If I change the option, it will generate a list based on it's value.

Here is the jquery code i use to generate the list :

```
jQuery('#group').change(function() {
   var id_group = this.value; 
   var memberjson = "fetchmember.php?group="+id_group;

   jQuery.getJSON(memberjson,function(data){

     jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
     jQuery("#fetchmember").append("<li>"+item.name+"</li>");
     });
   }); 
});
```

Html code :

```
<ul class="pagination3" id=fetchmember"></ul>
```

jQuery config (for paginate)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("ul.pagination3").quickPagination({pagerLocation:"both",pageSize:"5"});
});
```

What's wrong with my code? It can't work, but if I create static `<li>` like :

```
<ul class="pagination3" id=fetchmember">
<li>ONE</li>
<li>TWO</li>
<li>THREE</li>
</ul>
```

The pagination can work well. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: you called pagination function in document.ready the li append after this one so call the function again whenever you append the li

Comment: Use `.on()` method for attaching events

Comment: @SridharR How to call the function when I append the li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

Add this one your function call

```
$("ul.pagination3").quickPagination({pagerLocation:"both",pageSize:"5"});
```

Then code will be

```
jQuery('#group').change(function() {
   var id_group = this.value; 
   var memberjson = "fetchmember.php?group="+id_group;

   jQuery.getJSON(memberjson,function(data){

     jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
     jQuery("#fetchmember").append("<li>"+item.name+"</li>");
     $("ul.pagination3").quickPagination({pagerLocation:"both",pageSize:"5"});//now we have li elements in dom so it will work
     });
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea from your answer. I have to put the function quickPagination below the `append`, but it should be placed outside the `.each`