# Phonegap Jquery Pagination for loading contacts - how to add pages dynamically when user reaches last page?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, pagination

I have a specific scenario for which I will need to use pagination.

In Phonegap while loading from Android contacts, as the user goes through the pages, when the user clicks on the last page in pagination, I want another set of contact lists to be loaded dynamically into new set of pages added to the existing pagination.

I am doing this since I have to load a list of over 1000 contacts, which I don't want to load on the initial shot itself - even if its only pagination.

I found links to create pages dynamically, but none had my specific requirement(of loading new lists into new pages when user reaches last page).

This link [jQuery pagination with dynamic <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762107/jquery-pagination-with-dynamic-li) is the best link I found so far, but still I need a way to identify if user has reached the last page or not, in pagination.

NOTE: This is not an ajax request, its a phone gap api which gets contacts from native android contacts, and I have to iterate manually through the object and create lists dynamically on the fly.

Moreover since the pagination buttons when using pagination plugins come by default, I don't know how to add events to those page buttons or tweak them.

my code snippet:

```
navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);

function onSuccess(contacts) {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if ($.trim(contacts[i].displayName).length != 0 || $.trim(contacts[i].nickName).length != 0) {
        html += '<li>';
        html += '<h2>' + contacts[i].displayName ? contacts[i].displayName : contacts[i].nickName + '</h2>';
        if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers) {
            html += '<ul class="innerlsv" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
            html += '<li><h3>Phone Numbers</h3></li>';
            for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) { var dialPadVar = '#main-wrapper'; 
                html += "<li onclick=\"contactAppendNumber('"+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value+"');changePage('#main-wrapper');\">Type: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].type + "<br/>" +
                    "Value: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "<br/>" +
                    "Preferred: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].pref + "</li>";
            }
            html += "</ul>";
        }
        html += '</li>';
    }
}
if (contacts.length === 0) {
    html = '<li data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false">';
    html += '<h2>No Contacts</h2>';
    html += '<label>No Contacts Listed</label>';
    html += '</li>';
}
$("#contactsList").html(html);
$("#contactsList").listview().listview('refresh');
$(".innerlsv").listview().listview('refresh');

}
```

Comment: What have you done? To your description, I don't think there is any difficulty in loading extra items (from server) when one of the page buttons is clicked, either by AJAX or not.

Comment: @mrmoment Sorry for not being precise, I am loading Android Contacts using Phonegap, so its not an ajax call. Also the pagination buttons when using plugins come by default, so I don't know how to add events to those page buttons or tweak them. I have edited my question please take a relook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met your problem before - the typical `navigation.contacts.find()` returns all current contacts and it's more than 1000. And the `filter` parameter is not good to pagination.

After I got the contacts array, I divided them into pages (50 per page), but the contacts are actually all loaded anyway.

I think the best way is to refine the `PhoneGap` API to allow offset and limit on returned contacts. One work-around could be loading the contacts for the first time and manage them by yourself afterwards (e.g., writing records to local sqlite).

To the `jQuery` plugin, if I'm doing with it, I just need to use tools (e.g., Chrome) to observe the pagination button `IDs` or `class names` and add a listener on them upon `$(document).ready()`.

In case you are meaning that the buttons are not rendered in the beginning so you cannot bind listeners on themselves, you may need `$(document).on('click','button.pagination', function(){...});` which asks the parent node (here I use document directly) to act as an agent for the event. The `'button.pagination'` is the pagination buttons that are dynamically generated (change to the proper element in you case).

Answer (score 0):

However in order to achieve native speeds, I am using a plugin to invoke the native contacts app for android

If anyone has my problem they can use this method as it gives the best performance possible on device.

Reference links

[How to implement contacts filter in android phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892072/how-to-implement-contacts-filter-in-android-phonegap)

https://github.com/hazemhagrass/ContactPicker